# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver OSGi out from Eclipse

Tags: osgi, classnotfoundexception

I have been working on getting my OSGi application to run outside eclipse. In my eclipse environment the code:

```
new net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver()
```

works properly, but when I export the application I have the problem    `ClassNotFoundException`.

If I use `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()` it works, but not with jtds.
The library jtds and ojdbc14 are in the same directory and the manifest is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: DataSource plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.xxxx.jdbc_1.0.0
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.w7
Bundle-Activator: com.xxxx.jdbc.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: XXXX
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: javax.sql,
org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
org.osgi.service.jdbc;version="1.0.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar,
lib/org.apache.commons.pool.jar,
lib/ojdbc14.jar,
lib/jtds-1.3.1.jar
```

any ideas?